# R: How to subset columns based on values of the first row?

Tags: r, subset

I want to make a subset of columns according to a certain value in the first row. Here an example:

```
df <- data.frame( region = c("A", sample(1:5,3)),
                  region = c("B", sample(1:5,3)),
                  region = c("C", sample(1:5,3)),
                  region = c("A", sample(1:5,3)) )

> df
  region region.1 region.2 region.3
1      A        B        C        A
2      5        5        3        3
3      2        1        5        4
4      4        2        1        5
```

I want to subset all columns that show an `A` in the first row. I can't do this using index numbers as I have more than 3000 columns in my dataset and the names of the colnames are also important thats why I'm using the first row as a second header. The result for this example should return:

```
  region  region.3
1      A         A
2      5         3
3      2         4
4      4         5
```

And how can I avoid the automatic counting in the colnames for same names (region.1, region.2...)? Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: `df[unlist(df[1, ]) == "A"]` is probably what you want, but that's a bad way to set up data with mixed characters and numerics.

Comment: thank you for the advertence, but I need this row only for this beginning subset. In the next step I remove the first row and I will only work with the colnames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use index as in

```
> df[, df[1, ] == "A"]
  region region.3
1      A        A
2      3        1
3      2        5
4      1        4
```

Try using `check.names=FALSE` for your second question

```
> data.frame( region = c("A", sample(1:5,3)),
+             region = c("B", sample(1:5,3)),
+             region = c("C", sample(1:5,3)),
+             region = c("A", sample(1:5,3)), check.names=FALSE )
  region region region region
1      A      B      C      A
2      5      5      4      2
3      2      1      5      5
4      4      2      2      4
```